# Youtube Embed videos autoplay

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, embed, autoplay

I've an iframe which I use to embed the videos of a channel to an html page. This web page is used for digital signage so no one will be able to navigate. My problem is that the videos of the channel don't start automatically although I used *&autoplay=1*.
Here is the code:

```
<iframe width="480" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=NBA&loop=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it will work,

mistake i noticed here, `embed/video_id` was not found

```
<iframe width="480" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/eF5fRl3BMTY?listType=user_uploads&list=NBA&loop=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your video contains content from the NBA, and that it is restricted from playback or certain sites/applications.

I've tried another YouTube video with the same code and it worked. Perhaps try another video?

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1sDH1UBXI44?autoplay=1&listType=user_uploads&list=NBA&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1sDH1UBXI44?autoplay=1&listType=user_uploads&list=NBA&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1sDH1UBXI44?autoplay=1&listType=user_uploads&list=NBA&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When answering questions you should explain your solution. In this case it isn't clear what you have changed from the authors versions without comparing it myself.